# Create Combo Chart Within Sheets Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to create a combo chart on the same google sheet that contains the data. If there was a 'combo' option to 'setChartType' then this would be easy.

I have tried to use 'var = query new google.visualization.Query(https://)' but the 'google not defined' error results. How may I create a combo chart within a google sheet using scripts?

The following snippet of code creates a dual axis bar chart, but I require that one of the axes be a line (not all of the code is listed).

```
var cellContent = sheet.getRange(1,4); 
var chartMgr = cellContent.getValue(); //get content of cell A4

var posX = 2;
    var posY = 17;
    var width = 800;
    var xTitle = 'Category';
    var yTitle = 'Number of Defects';
    var chartType = Charts.ChartType.COLUMN;

var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
      chartBuilder.addRange(range)
      .setPosition(posY, posX, 0, 0)
      .setOption('title', 'Flow Defect Details - ' + chartMgr)
      .setOption('width', width)
      .setOption('vAxis.title', yTitle)
      .setOption('hAxis.title', xTitle)
      .setChartType(chartType);
      sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
```

Comment: You can not use `var query = new google.visualization.Query(https://)` on servers side. This is the client side feature which requires client library to be included. If you want to use this query feature, you will have to use HtmlServices in GAS.

Comment: Thank you. Any advice on how to create a combo chart on the server side using data entered on the sheet?

Comment: You can use apps scripts' UI services to create charts. Have a look at [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/?csw=1).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there isn't a combo chart builder in apps script as yet, you can set one of the series on your column chart to be a line using `.setOption()`.

The series numbering seems to start from 0, so if, for example, you want series 2 as a line, just add `.setOption('series', {1: {type: 'line'}})` when you're building your chart.